# Как правильно перевести на C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Код C#:

```
public struct Point
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
}

Point a, b, c, d, k, f, m;

Point[] RP;

public void GenerationPoints(int N)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    RP = new Point[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        RP[i].x = rnd.Next(a.x + 1, c.x);
        RP[i].y = rnd.Next(a.y + 1, c.y);
    }
}
```

Попытка перевода на C++/CLI:

```
ref struct Point
{
    public: int x;
    public: int y;
};

Point a, b, c, d, k, f, m;



public: void GenerationPoints(int n)
{
     array<Point^ >^ pr = gcnew array<Point^ >(n);        
     Random ^ rnd = gcnew Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pr[i].x = rnd->Next(a.x + 1, c.x);
        pr[i].y = rnd->Next(a.y + 1, c.y);
    }
}
```

Ошибка вот  здесь  pr[i].x = rnd->Next(a.x + 1, c.x);
            pr[i].y = rnd->Next(a.y + 1, c.y); не указывает на экземпляр написанол

Comment: покажите как вы это неправильно сделали.

Comment: ref struct Point
        {
  public: int x;
  public: int y;
        };
  
  Point a, b, c, d, k, f, m;
array< Point^ >^ pr = gcnew array< Point^ >();
     
public: void GenerationPoints(int n)
        {

   Random ^rnd = gcnew Random();
   
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
    pr[i].x = rnd->Next(a.x + 1, c.x);
    pr[i].y = rnd->Next(a.y + 1, c.y);
            }
        }

Comment: Ну в принципе, всё правильно. Единственно, нужно ещё задавать размер массива: `pr = gcnew array<Point^ >(n);`. И чтобы код в точности соответствовал оригиналу, нужно перенести эту инициализацию массива внутрь метода (но это не обязательно).

Comment: я сделал так , компилируется, но выходит ошибка об осуствии ссылки на экземпляр

Comment: Замените массив ссылок на массив структур: `array<Point>^ pr = gcnew array<Point>(n);` Обратите внимание на отсутствие значка `^`.

Comment: Заменил и теперь он пишет нельзя так без галочек нет дескрипторов